# Error:The method elementToBeClickable(By) in the type ExpectedConditions is not applicable for the arguments (WebElement)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait

I am novice to Selenium and trying to walk through some code.
It uses Explicit Wait as below functions in Utils.java file.

```
public static void waitForElement(WebElement element){

     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));

        }
```

When I compile it gives the error :-

> The method elementToBeClickable(By) in the type ExpectedConditions is not applicable for the arguments (WebElement)

Comment: Let me emphasize it for you "The method elementToBeClickable(**By**) in the type **ExpectedConditions** ". Go to JavaSoc and look what kind of parameters the `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable` expects. In other words, Read That F...ine Manual.

Comment: Are you sure this exception occurred because [`ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) also accept `WebElement`??

Comment: Which version of selenium are you using??

Answer (score 1):

It is very clear from the error message that the method
 `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable()` can accept only the type `By`. you cannot directly pass a web element as a parameter to the method.

have a look at https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html to know the list of expectedconditions and their parameters.

Comment: No, [`ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) also accept `WebElement`

Answer (score 0):

> The method elementToBeClickable(By) in the type ExpectedConditions is not applicable for the arguments (WebElement)

It looks like you're using [old version of selenium <= 2.37.0](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-support/2.37.0/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java#ExpectedConditions) where `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable` accept only `By` object as a parameter.

But from [selenium version >= 2.38.0](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-support/2.38.0/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java#ExpectedConditions) [`ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) accept `By` as well as `WebElement` object as parameter.

I would suggest you [upgrade your selenium version to latest stable version 2.53.0](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.53/) or [>= 2.38.0](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) to get rid from this exception.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few different ways to use Explicit Wait to command different actions.

presenceOfElementLocated - This defines an expectation of identifying an element at the DOM level, such as recognizing that the button exists on the page.
visibilityOfElementLocated - This defines an expectation of identifying an element is present at the DOM level and visible so that the button is there and the user could see it.
visibilityOfAllElementsLocated - This checks that all elements are identified and visible, such as a button and an image.
elementToBeClickable - This defines an expectation to check for a visible element and click it, such as clicking a button.

```
public class One_dynamic {
WebDriver driver;
WebDriverWait wait;

@BeforeTest
public void browserlaunch() throws Throwable, Throwable {
    System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_SILENT_OUTPUT_PROPERTY, "true");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/dynamic_loading");
}

@Test
public void dynamicwait() {

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'oading/1')]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Start']")).click();
    
    
    WebElement abc = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h4[text()='Hello World!']"));
    
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(abc));
    
    String helloworld = "Hello World!";
    System.out.println(helloworld);
    System.out.println(abc.getText());

    Assert.assertEquals(helloworld, abc.getText());
}

@AfterTest
public void teardown() {
    driver.quit();
}
```

}