# How do I do a find by className on Microsoft Edge?

Tags: selenium, microsoft-edge

I am trying to run Selenium tests on Microsoft Edge, but they do not appear to work at all.

I am running on Windows 10 Build 10586.842, therefore I downloaded Microsoft WebDriver Release 10586. Also using Microsoft EdgeHTML 13.10586.

Nothing works on here.
Cannot do a simple find by className.

```
@FindBy(className="login-load-logo") private WebElement logo;
```

This is the line I am trying to find:

```
<img class="login-load-logo" style="transition:none; top: 29px;" src="assets/images/logo-big.svg?v=f17fe5f5040aea3652ea417726b601437456196e">
```

This little routine should wait for it to become visible:

```
private void waitForVisibility(WebElement element) throws Error {

    try {

        new WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("An error has occurred in Alloy Home Page process.");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

I am getting a TimeoutException here, even though I can clearly see the element on the screen.

Comment: Can you share the relevant `HTML` and your code trials?

Comment: Share your HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following expected condition in your method:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(element));
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: I get an error with that: The method presenceOfElementLocated(By) in the type ExpectedConditions is not applicable for the arguments (WebElement)

Comment: @SteveStaple, try to figure out -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739025/errorthe-method-elementtobeclickableby-in-the-type-expectedconditions-is-not.

Comment: I figured out OK, and presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpathExpression)) definitely works. However, element.isDisplayed doesn't.

Comment: @SteveStaple, if my answer was helpful -- check a tick near my answer, please.

Comment: @SteveStaple, from official documentation:

presenceOfElementLocated(locator):
An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible. locator - used to find the element returns the WebElement once it is located

Answer (score 0):

Can try using the following :

```
@FindBy(XPATH="//img[@class='login-load-logo' and contains(@src,'assets/images/logo-big.svg')]") 
private WebElement logo;
```

---

### Update :

Your code doesn't throws any light towards the action you want to perform on the `WebElement` identified as **element**. Incase next you are trying to invoke `click()` mehtod on it, instead of `ExpectedConditions` clause as **`visibilityOf()`** try using **`elementToBeClickable(element)`** as follows :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
```

Comment: that is because there isn't any action to be performed on the element! I am using it to confirm that the page has loaded. How is that relevant to the question?

Comment: @SteveStaple The choice of `ExpectedConditions` will depend on your next course of action.

Comment: elementToBeClickable does not appear to work on Microsoft Edge either.

Comment: Can you update the question with the full error stack trace?

Comment: thank you @DebanjanB. elementToBeClickable worked OK on Edge using a PC with a more recent OS build.